# How do you fetch a large file over http in parallel?

Tags: wget, http, parallelism, bandwidth, thread

**Question:**

Since HTTP supports resuming at an offset, are there any tools (or existing options for commands like wget or curl) that will launch multiple threads to fetch the file in parallel with multiple requests at different file offsets? This could help with performance of each socket is throttled separately.

I could write a program to do this, but I'm wondering if the tooling already exists.

**Background:**

Recently I wanted to download a large iso, **but!** ... Somewhere between the server and my internet provider the transfer rate was limited to 100 kilobit! However, I noticed that the first 5 to 10 seconds had great throughput,  hundreds of megabits. So I wrote a small bash script to restart after a few seconds:

```
while ! timeout 8 wget -c http://example.com/bigfile.iso; do true; done
```

(I hope it was not my provider . . . But maybe it was. Someone please bring back net neutrality!)

Comment: found [aria2](https://aria2.github.io/) by searching for *linux download using multiple sockets* - but the issue may well be the **total** upstream bandwidth available to the source of the file - in which case, nothing will improve the download speed

Comment: @JaromandaX, Neat!  Of course this is to work around throttling, I realize a true bandwidth limit cannot be fixed...and indeed multiple TCP streams would only add more overhead.